# Calculated Field Won't Turn Into Dimension

Tags: tableau-api

So in the YouTube API, we are given AverageViewDuration and AverageViewPercentage. We are not given the Duration of the video, so I came up with a calculation to get the “Duration”, which is:

```
MAX([Averageviewduration])/MAX(([Averageviewpercentage])*.01)
```

When I put Video ID in rows and bring in Duration, it shows the correct duration for each video ID – which is great!

```
Video A: 1,300 seconds
Video B: 60 seconds
Video C: 150 seconds
etc.
```

The problem now is that I want to create groups for the duration, but my calculated field is not changing into a measure. This is what I wrote:

```
IF [Duration]<60 THEN "1) <1 Min"
ELSEIF [Duration]<120 THEN "2) 1:00 to 1:59"
ELSEIF [Duration]<180 THEN "3) 2:00 to 2:59"
ELSEIF [Duration]<360 THEN "4) 3:00 to 5:59"
ELSEIF [Duration]<600 THEN "5) 6:00 to 9:59"
ELSEIF [Duration]<1200 THEN "6) 10:00 to 19:59"
ELSEIF [Duration]>=1200 THEN "7) 20 Mins +"
END
```

I want to have this:

```
Duration Group     Count of Videos     Average Views
1) <1 Min                50               1,000
2) 1:00 to 1:59          29               4,290
3) 2:00 to 2:59          65               2,201
etc
```

I tried adding a level of detail to the duration calculation, but it didn’t work (I may have done it incorrectly haha). The groups work when I drag Duration Groups and Video ID into rows, but I want to be able to group the Average Views, Average View Duration, etc. without having Video ID in there. I sort of understand why it's not working, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculated field `Duration` isn't an attribute for each `Video ID`, is an aggregation function that can be calculated for `Video ID` or other dimensions. That's why there is a problem with the your calculated field for grouping videos.

A solution for this may be use a [Level of Detail Expression](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) for Duration:

```
{FIXED [Video ID]: MAX([Averageviewduration])/MAX(([Averageviewpercentage])*.01)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data structured with one row per Video ID, where each Video ID has an AverageViewDuration and AverageViewPercentage? If yes, then not sure of the reason to wrap in max in your calculated field:

```
MAX([Averageviewduration])/MAX(([Averageviewpercentage])*.01)
```

If instead you make the field:

```
[Averageviewduration]/([Averageviewpercentage]*.01)
```

Then I think you could do what you are describing.